# How to use wildcards to auto-complete on remote server in zsh?

Tags: command-line, autocomplete, zsh

One of my favorite features of zsh is auto-complete, especially when I'm completing a filename on a networked machine. But how do you include wildcards (like *) and have it auto-complete on the remote machine?

For instance, say I have file1, file2, and file3 residing on a server; I want to copy all those files to my local machine, so I enter

```
scp server:~/fi<tab>
```

zsh then correctly auto-completes to

```
scp server:~/file
```

but then when I try to wildcard

```
scp server:~/file*<tab>
```

all it does it beep at me (it works correctly if the file paths are local). Is there a set of zsh options that makes this work?  I found GLOB_COMPLETE and EXTENDED_GLOB, but the best I could do with any combination of those was to auto-complete a single match, or cycle through all matches, but not expand the auto-complete to ***all*** matches (as it does on the local command line).  Is that actually possible?

Thanks!
randy

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: You would have to write a completion function that would actually ssh into the remote host and retrieve a list of files.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson This function already exists and gives good results. The question is how to push all its results into command line at once.

Comment: Yes, Dennis, and I alluded to that in my OP.  So, what's the answer to "The question is how to push all its results into command line at once."? :)

Comment: Paul, it's on SU; I posted it there first, and it's gotten no responses whatsoever.  At least I got a bite here on SO...

Answer (score 1):

As I've mentioned at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/235412/zsh-autocomplete-wildcard-across-the-network/429953#429953): Think setting GLOB_COMPLETE should change this.

```
setopt GLOB_COMPLETE
```

From `man zshoptions`:

> GLOB_COMPLETE
>
> When the current word has a glob pattern, do not insert all the words resulting from the expansion but generate matches as for completion and cycle through them like MENU_COMPLETE. The matches are generated as if a ‘*’ was added to the end of the word, or inserted at the cursor when COMPLETE_IN_WORD is set. This actually uses pattern matching, not globbing, so it works not only for files but for any completion, such as options, user names, etc.
>
> Note that when the pattern matcher is used, matching control (for example, case-insensitive or anchored matching) cannot be used. This limitation only applies when the current word contains a pattern; simply turning on the GLOB_COMPLETE option does not have this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works perfectly fine for me. I don't know what makes it work on my system, but here's what I have set:(
alwaystoend
cbases
extendedglob
interactive
interactivecomments
monitor
shinstdin). And my .zshrc has:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored _correct _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' max-errors 1 numeric
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
autoload -Uz compinit zsh-mime-setup
compinit
```

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem !
I suceed with the follwing command:
scp "user@server:/dir/*" localdir

double quote escapes the completion.